# How to correctly filter Package replaced broadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast, intentfilter

I am trying to catch the package replaced broadcast for my app and only my app, but for some reason in my reciever I am the broadcast for every app that is updated.  I thought you only needed to set the intent filter in the manifest file to your app, but maybe I am wrong?

Here's my code(manifest):

```
        <receiver android:name=".UpdateReciever">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <data android:scheme="package" android:path="com.my.app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Reciever:

```
public class AppUpdateReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context con, Intent intent) {

        //code..    
    }

}
```

Comment: From my tests, the `android:path` portion is unnecessary.

Comment: If you provide the path in the filter then it is unnecessary to check the data again in the receiver. Check [Intent and Filters](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) and [intents you may need](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Add this to your onReceive method:

```
if (intent.getDataString().contains("com.my.app")){
    ...
}
```

**EDIT:**
Note that registering for `ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED` causes your app to be started up every time any app is updated, if it wasn't already open. I don't know how to avoid this before API 12, but in API 12 you can register for `ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` so you don't have to filter the intent and your app won't be started unnecessarily by other apps being updated.

Comment: so there is no way to register only to intents of the current app? it seems a google developer (named "Dianne Hackborn") thinks it is possible : http://osdir.com/ml/Android-Developers/2009-11/msg04736.html

Comment: That implies that there was a way, but I never figured it out. In Honeycomb, you can use `ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` to avoid the problem with `ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED

Comment: yes, but I can't find the older way, so what i've done is a fallback which uses both methods, as i've shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21510561/878126 .

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, if your code is in a library that's included in multiple apps, or if you just want something that can be copy/pasted between apps without edits:

```
int intentUid = intent.getExtras().getInt("android.intent.extra.UID");
int myUid = android.os.Process.myUid();
if (intentUid == myUid)
{
    ...
}
```