# Starting an Android service with AlarmManager and Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I have a background Android service. It runs in background, checks an URL for some results. And if results change, app sends a notification to user. I want this service to run every 3 hours. My problem is when and how to start the service ?

- General behaviour is to create a Broadcast receiver.
- Then start service when receiver gets a `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`.
- Also when receiver gets a boot completed, receiver will use AlarmManager and will create an alarm to run every 3 hours.

But after installing the application, what if the user doesn't restart his/her phone ?  If user doesn't boot, AlarmManager won't create an alarm.

- So another option is to create alarm when user first runs the application.
- What if user restarts the application ? Should I cancel all previous alarms with `AlarmManager.cancel` and recreate the alarms ?

So in which conditions do you set alarms for your Android applications ?

Comment: AFAIK, setting up an alarm for a given PendingIntent (based on a given Intent) cancels previous alarms for the same Intent. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to create the initial alarm, either when the app is started for the first time, or even better, have another broadcast receiver listening for `ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED`. This is called whenever the app is installed or updated, and you can set up the alarm when that or a reboot happens (because a reboot clears alarms from the alarm manager). Then simply reset your alarm every time the service runs.

As an additional tip, check the Android `WakeLock` documentation in case you don't use them yet. Without setting a wake lock when the service is started, the phone might go to sleep right after the service's `onStartCommand`. And make sure resetting the alarm is done even if you run into some error situation (e.g. missing network connection) within the service.

Edit: Some people have had problems with `ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED`. In these cases, `ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED` can be used as long as the code checks that it's the correct package that was replaced: [ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED not received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666734/action-my-package-replaced-not-received)

Comment: I get "ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" when I update my app. But it isn't triggered on new installations.

Comment: "ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED" doesn't always work for me. So it seems like I need to set alarms on ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED, on ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED. Also I need to set alarms on each run of my app, else my service won't be started until a reboot or app update.