# How to keep running Service when app updated in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, service, widget, receiver

I am developing clock Widget application in android, I have one Foreground service which is running in background, but issue is when I update the app, service has been stopped. How to keep service running after app update, I tried ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED and placed in Broadcast Receiver but did not worked, I cant get onReceive call in that particular Receiver.

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing in Android Studio, it might not be firing that broadcast at all. [This question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64579518/13598222) gets into it - if you install through `adb install` you get the broadcast, if you install with Run in AS it doesn't happen.

You basically need to build your app (either `Rebuild` in the `Build` menu, or with `gradlew assembleDebug` on the command line) and then run `adb install app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk` (or whatever the path is, depends where you're running it) and it should work. I'd recommend putting a log call in your receiver so you can see if it runs or not

Also make sure your receiver has `android:exported=true` and `android:enabled=true` in the manifest