# Automatically return to app after update

Tags: android, google-play, alarmmanager

We have a security camera android application. That means it stays on while the user is not around. When we release a new version, if Google Play is configured to update automatically, the app closes. This is obviously a problem. Replicating it using `adb install` I saw that `onDestroy` isn't even called. How do I make it so the app will return after the update is complete? One idea I had in mind is using `AlarmManager` that tries to run the activity every 15 minutes or so until the user closes it properly, but it seems inefficient. Is there better way?

Comment: Opening an Activity every 15 minutes is very bad idea also will be annoying user. Seems you need a Service instead of activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is intent which fires after updating app: [`android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED). So just add receiver and launch your service of whatever you need.

Prior 12 API level you can use [ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED). But it fires each time when any app updates. Sample here: [How to correctly filter Package replaced broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513825/how-to-correctly-filter-package-replaced-broadcast)

Comment: Looks good, but our app's minimum API is 8, and this requires 12.

Comment: @AsafSchreiber there is another intent which could help you. I've updated answer.