# How to find out that application was updated

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to do something in code only when application was updated directly from Google Play (or automatically)?

My task is to ask user about some terms of privacy police just after installing or after every updating

Comment: You can do it by using a package replaced receiver. Here's an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513825/how-to-correctly-filter-package-replaced-broadcast)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED` receiver to detect when your app is updated.
According to doc:

> Broadcast Action: A new version of an application package has been
>   installed, replacing an existing version that was previously
>   installed. The data contains the name of the package.

**AndroidMenifest.xml:**
Register a receiver with `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED` action.

```
<receiver android:name=".OnUpgradeReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
    <data android:scheme="package" android:path="your.app.package" />
  </intent-filter>
</receive>
```

**AppUpdateReceiver.java:**
Create broadcast receiver that will trigger when your app is updated. Check for your version code and perform the specific action.

```
public class AppUpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        switch (BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE){
            case 1:
                //DO something if the version code is 1.
                break;
            case 2:
                //DO something if the version code is 2.
                break;
            ...
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this looks good, but passsy suggested (in my opinion) more simple solution.  What is advantage of your way?

Comment: You don't have to check for the app version and check if the app updated each time. System will call your app, whenever your app is updated.

Answer (score 1):

Simply check if `BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE` has changed. 
To do this save the version code in the `SharedPreferences`.
`Application#onCreate()` could be a good point for this.

Comment: Sorry, your solution is good and simple, but way of Keval Patel looks more right. I vote up to your question, but I accepted an answer of Keval

Answer (score 0):

You can update the code simply (of showing policy to the user on launch) and when the user would launch the app next time it should show up. Maybe keep a preference value to ensure it only happens once.

Alternatively, you can also read the current version code on each launch and keep storing it as a preference and once it gets updated, you can show the policy and also update the stored value.

Answer (score 0):

Store the `BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE` in sharedpreference. Each time user opens the app, fetch the Version code and compare with the stored data.